# Как перекомпилировать проект под более ранним jdk

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Проект был скомпилирован под JDK 13 нужно перекомпилировать его под JDK 6, как это можно сделать через intellij idea, если можно то подробнее куда заходить и что делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Соответствующий раздел документации](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/java-compiler.html#compiler).